# storyboard file main~iphone.storyboardc was not found error when trying to submit binary to itunes connect

Tags: binary, storyboard, bundle, app-store-connect

When I try to submit to the app store from xcode, I get this error for both Main~ipad.storyboardc and Main~iphone.storyboardc:
"ERROR ITMS-90029: "Storyboard file 'Main~iphone.storyboardc' was not found. Please ensure the specified file is included in the bundle with any required device modifiers appended to the filename."

I've looked at all similar questions posted to stackoverflow and tried their suggestions with no luck.

My app is for iphone ONLY, does not use storyboard, and runs perfectly well on all iphone simulators without errors.

Now when I go back to a snapshot of when the project ran well on simulators, the project no longer runs...I get error "Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?"

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I deleted the Main.Storyboard file from my project.  I thought it would be OK to delete that file since I wasn't using it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that I switched my supported devices from `universal` to `iPad` only. I had also changed the name of the `Main.storyboard` file but after I had updated the supported devices. So the `Main storyboard file base name` entry in the info.plist file was still `Main.storyboard`.

Deleting the entire row for `Main storyboard file base name` and leaving `Main storyboard file base name (iPad)` in the info.plist file fixed the issue.

Since your project is iPhone only just make sure to remove `Main storyboard file base name (iPad)` completely.